# passing arguments to docker

Tags: bash, docker, continuous-integration

I am trying to pass an argument to docker. For that, I use build-arg in my docker build command.

```
echo "[INFO] Hadoop version is ${HDP_VERSION}"
docker build --no-cache=true --squash \
--build-arg HDP_VERSION=${HDP_VERSION} \
```

This is my docker

```
ARG HDP_VERSION
FROM host:5000/runner-hadoop:${HDP_VERSION}
RUN echo "HDP_VERSION="${HDP_VERSION}
COPY oozie/${HDP_VERSION} ${PATH_UNIX_PROJECT}
```

The first and second row execute without failing, but after that, I see that `HDP_VERSION` is actually empty. So at step 4, the wrong directory is taken.

[image]

Why is that and how do you correct it?

EDIT

This is the result of echo

[image]

This is what I get if I use

```
--build-arg HDP_VERSION=1 \
```

[image]

EDIT2

This is what happens if I use ENV. The result is the same.

```
ENV HDP_VERSION=${HDP_VERSION}
RUN echo "HDP_VERSION="${HDP_VERSION}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your variable is set on your host ? Could you show the content of `echo $HDP_VERSION` outside of docker ? Do you have the same behaviour when you write `--build-arg HDP_VERSION=1` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to repeat the `ARG` after each `FROM` line; see for example [Multi-stage Dockerfile: ARG before FROM not substituted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53681522/multi-stage-dockerfile-arg-before-from-not-substituted).  (This will be easier to read and search for later if you post the actual textual output of `docker build` and similar commands, rather than images.)

Comment: @david thanks. this worked.

Answer (score 0):

`ARG` is not `ENV`. `ARG` is taking argument to docker so it's visible to docker, `ENV` exports variable to environment so it's visible to `RUN`.

```
ARG HDP_VERSION
FROM host:5000/runner-hadoop:${HDP_VERSION}
ENV HDP_VERSION=${HDP_VERSION}
RUN echo "HDP_VERSION="${HDP_VERSION}
COPY oozie/${HDP_VERSION} ${PATH_UNIX_PROJECT}
```

Comment: The result is the same. I updated my post.