# 'cannot normalize nothing' error on Docker Hub multi-stage build with shared ARG

Tags: dockerfile, dockerhub

I have a multi-stage build sharing single `ARG` (to DRY out path) between stages. Something like this:

```
ARG BUILD_DIR=/build

FROM alpine:latest as build
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev
WORKDIR $BUILD_DIR
RUN echo -e '\n\
#include <stdio.h>\n\
int main (void)\n\
{ puts ("Hello, World!");}'\
>> hello.c
RUN cc -o hello hello.c

FROM alpine:latest
COPY --from=build $BUILD_DIR/hello /app
CMD ["/app"]
```

It gets built with no problem locally, but automated Docker Hub build fails with the following error:

> Step 4/9 : WORKDIR $BUILD_DIR
> cannot normalize nothing

I am curious, what can cause the problem (too old build engine on Docker Hub?). And is there a better workaround than just hard-coding path in Dockerfile?

Comment: If you want to use the arg inside a step you have to put another `ARG BUILD_DIR` after `FROM ...`

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes, thank you. I already referenced this question in my solution I posted below yesterday. Since my local Docker silently and successfully produced the build from Dockerfile from my question, initially I did not even realize that `ARG` substitution did not work. I faced the error only on automated Docker Hub build.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53682110/3581539) that I need to renew `ARG` on each step I want to reuse it. Quoting docs:

> An `ARG` instruction goes out of scope at the end of the build stage where it was defined. To use an arg in multiple stages, each stage must include the `ARG` instruction.

The fixed `Dockerfile` is:

```
ARG BUILD_DIR=/build

FROM alpine:latest as build
ARG BUILD_DIR # <----------------------------------
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev
WORKDIR $BUILD_DIR
RUN echo -e '\n\
#include <stdio.h>\n\
int main (void)\n\
{ puts ("Hello, World!");}'\
>> hello.c
RUN cc -o hello hello.c

FROM alpine:latest
ARG BUILD_DIR # <----------------------------------
COPY --from=build $BUILD_DIR/hello /app
CMD ["/app"]
```

It means that an `ARG` value from the code in my initial question does not even work. Interesting, that my Docker For Mac ignores the problem and silently uses empty `BUILD_DIR` argument for `WORKDIR` producing successful build. While Docker Hub automated builder fails with an error explicitly.