# Unable to use Arg values in commands in dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am trying to allow passing build args to a dockerfile during build process but I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-server -y \
     && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 2222
ARG node_build=production
ENV node_build_env=$node_build
ARG net_build=Release
ENV net_build_env=$net_build

FROM node:12.18.3 AS node-build

RUN echo $build_command_env
WORKDIR /root
COPY ["MyProject/package.json", "."]
COPY ["MyProject/package-lock.json", "."]
RUN npm i --ignore-scripts
COPY ["MyProject/angular.json", "."]
COPY ["MyProject/tsconfig.json", "."]
COPY ["MyProject/tslint.json", "."]
COPY ["MyProject/src", "./src"]

RUN npx ng build -c $node_build_env

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build

RUN echo $net_build_env
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject/MyProject.csproj", "MyProject/"]
COPY ["MyProject.ServiceModel/MyProject.ServiceModel.csproj", "MyProject.ServiceModel/"]
COPY ["MyProject.ServiceInterface/MyProject.ServiceInterface.csproj", "MyProject.ServiceInterface/"]
COPY ["NuGet.config", "NuGet.config"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject/MyProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c $net_build_env -o /app

FROM build AS publish

RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c $net_build_env -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data --from=publish /app .
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data --from=node-build /root/wwwroot ./wwwroot
ENTRYPOINT service ssh start && dotnet MyProject.dll
```

I have tried many different ways.  I tried just using ARG and declaring after every FROM but that didn't work.  This version I try copying ARG to ENV but that also didn't work.

How do I do this?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: It doesn't substitute $node_build_env for the value.  Have tried with both ENV and ARG

Comment: please give us the `docker build` command you're using

Comment: `docker build -f MyProject\Dockerfile -t my:tag .`

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that variable had to be in double quote:

```
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c "$net_build_env" -o /app
```

Comment: I wonder why is this. Why double quotes matter in this case? `$net_build_env`'s value is single word and the command without double quote should just work fine

Comment: Also does this work if you use ARGs directly and don't use ENVs?

Comment: Another strange thing is it is building for me locally in windows now but wont build in docker hub

Comment: can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53682110/1003464) and see if it works?

Answer (score -1):

You have to add `--build-arg <arg>=<value>` in your docker build command in order to use `ARG` arguments in your containerfile.

There's no need for `ENV` if you're only going to use the args in container build process

Comment: I am providing default value so this is not required.  I have found issue, I needed to add double quotes around variable name.

Comment: Aha. you didn't mention that even default values didn't work